# Convergence of integration - test

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Question: Is there a way to evaluate convergence for complicated integrals in Mathematica?

I have a 12 dimensional integral - given by the following code

```
q3v = Table[q3[i], {i, 3}];
p3v = Table[p3[i], {i, 3}];
qv = Table[q[i], {i, 3}];
pv = Table[p[i], {i, 3}];
intvariables = Flatten[Join[{q3v}, {p3v}, {qv}, {pv}]]
intvariables2 = ({#1, -1, 1} & ) /@ intvariables

a := 1/(Sqrt[m^2 + pv . pv]*Sqrt[m^2 + p3v . p3v]*
 Sqrt[μ^2 + q3v . q3v]*
 Sqrt[μ^2 + (pv - p3v - q3v) . (pv - p3v - q3v)]);
b := 1/(Sqrt[m^2 + p3v . p3v]*Sqrt[m^2 + qv . qv]*
 Sqrt[μ^2 + q3v . q3v]*
 Sqrt[μ^2 + (-p3v + qv - q3v) . (-p3v + qv - q3v)]);
c := 1/(Sqrt[μ^2 + q3v . q3v] + 
 Sqrt[μ^2 + (-p3v - q3v + qv) . (-p3v - q3v + qv)]);
e := 1/(pv . pv + 1^2)^2;
f := 1/(qv . qv + 1^2)^2;
```

and then

```
jj = FullSimplify[a*b*c]; 
TraditionalForm[jj]
```

[Comment: if I try FullSimplify[a b c e f], Mathematica 10 and 11 just hang..]

If I now try

```
jjm = jj //. {μ -> 1., m -> 1.}
```

followed by

```
NIntegrate[jjm*e*f, Evaluate[Sequence @@ intvariables2], MaxPoints -> 1000]
```

the result is `-22.54358093170731`

However, if the integration is done as

```
intvariables3 = ({#1, -100, 100} & ) /@ intvariables
NIntegrate[jjm*e*f, Evaluate[Sequence @@ intvariables3], MaxPoints -> 1000]
```

gives a completely different result

```
NIntegrate::maxp: The integral failed to converge after 13227 integrand evaluations. NIntegrate obtained -3.78792*10^23 and 1.2256724176744906`*^24 for the integral and error estimates. >>
```

1. Is it normal for Mathematica to hang - for the command `jj = FullSimplify[a*b*c*e*f]; 
   TraditionalForm[jj]`
2. How does one test for convergence of integration, given that Mathematica won't integrate jjm symbolically, between -Infinity and Infinity.

Comment: Please put a notice in the question when cross-posted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1177659

Comment: I deleted my answer, because there was something wrong with the usage of Max.  I try to imporve it.